# Read data from excel in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, excel, textbox

I want to read a whole excel sheet's data in a single textbox.

Is this possible?

I know the code to read a cell's data from excel to a textbox.

```
PrivateSub Button18_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button18.Click

    Dim xlaTest As Excel.Application = CType(CreateObject("Excel.Application"), Excel.Application)
    xlaTest.Visible = True
    Dim wbkTest As Excel.Workbook = xlaTest.Workbooks.Open("D:\Tests\VBTrials\ExcelTests\TestWorkbook.xls")
    Dim wshTest As Excel.Worksheet = DirectCast(wbkTest.Worksheets("Sheet1"), Excel.Worksheet)
    TextBox1.Text = wshTest.Range("B2").Value
    wbkTest.Close()
    xlaTest.Quit()

EndSub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private List<object> Excelvoider()
        {
            Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
            Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@"C:/Temp/Книга1.xlsx");
            Excel._Worksheet xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets[1];
            Excel.Range xlRange = xlWorksheet.Range["B3", "Q58"];
            List<object> stroke = new List<object>();
            int rowCount = xlRange.Rows.Count;
            int colCount = xlRange.Columns.Count;
            for (int i = 1; i <= rowCount; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 1; j <= colCount; i++)
                {
                      stroke.Add(xlRange.Value2[i, j]);
                }
            }
            return stroke;
        }
```

This is Range from one cell to another:

```
Excel.Range xlRange = xlWorksheet.Range["B3", "Q58"];
```

You also can use xlWorksheet.UsedRange.

Comment: Hello, What should be the last cell to read instead of Q58. I mean I want the last cell that has data

Comment: Oh I got it. The last line of your post gives the answer of the above commented question

Comment: here stroke returns the single dimension array. Then how could my textbox look like excel worksheet?

Comment: Why you use textbox, how about GridView and etc?

Comment: because my application is designed for reading the textfiles. Now I want to add the fascility to read excel files

Comment: If I have GridView then how can I add data from your function to gridview?

Comment: xlRange.Value2[i,j] - this is object, contains data from one cell. cycle for iterate all cells, one by one. You can do with it what you want. For example: TextBox1.Text += "|" + xlRange.Value2[i,j] + "|";

Comment: About GridView - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.aspx